# Automatic jQuery accordion from header tags

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want it to be fairly easy for the post author to setup an accordion, based on header tags. So for example this:

```
<h3>Headline 1</h3>
<p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p>

<h3>Headline 2</h3>
<p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p>

<h3>Headline 3</h3>
<p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p>
```

would be converted to this (and so, accordion is activated)

```
<div class="accordion">
<h3>Headline 1</h3>
<div><p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p></div>
<h3>Headline 2</h3>
<div><p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p></div>
<h3>Headline 3</h3>
<div><p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p></div>
</div>
```

I've been using a setup with shortcodes — but this gets too complicated for the post author — so a more streamlined solution would be grand. Any ideas how I would go about doing this?

Answer (score 4):

You can use shortcode function to do this.

```
function accordion_shortcode( $atts, $content = null ) {
   extract( shortcode_atts( array(
      'class' => 'accordion',
      ), $atts ) );

   return '<div class="' . esc_attr($class) . '">' . $content . '</div>';
}

add_shortcode( 'accordion', 'accordion_shortcode' );
```

In editor you wrap your content:

```
[accordion]
<h3>Headline 1</h3>
<p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p>

<h3>Headline 2</h3>
<p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p>

<h3>Headline 3</h3>
<p>Content.. lorem ipsum</p>
[/accordion]
```